# DataFrame most efficient way update row value less than 40% to NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have big dataframe, need to find all element less than 40% in a row set to NaN, element not sorted, repeat this for each row.

I can force the calculation, but you can imagine it's not very efficient, there is no efficient way to do it?

40% mean row element order asc, and set low order 40% element to nan, does not contain an element that is itself a nan.
If I have ten element : `1,21,20,4,5,6,7,9,10,11`, should sort it to `1,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,20,21` and remove `1,4,5,6`, finally become `nan,21,20,nan,nan,nan,7,9,10,11`.

```
1  21  20  4  5  6  7  9  10  11
```

to

```
NaN  21  20 NaN NaN NaN  7  9  10  11
```

Comment: Do you think `need to find all element less than 40%` - first 40% of columns by lenght of columns (with remove missing columns) ?

Comment: How is count `40%` ?

Comment: @jezrael  order asc, remove 40%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for get number of non missing values per rows, then compare by positions of sorted values by double [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and last set missing values by mask:

```
print (df)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6    7   8   9     10
0   1   2   3  10   5   6   7  NaN   9   4  11.0
1   1  21  20   4   5   6   7  9.0  10  11   NaN

counts = df.count(axis=1).mul(0.4).to_numpy()[:, None]
arr = np.argsort(np.argsort(df.to_numpy()))

df[arr < counts] = np.nan
print (df)
   0     1     2     3    4    5   6    7   8     9     10
0 NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0  5.0  6.0   7  NaN   9   NaN  11.0
1 NaN  21.0  20.0   NaN  NaN  NaN   7  9.0  10  11.0   NaN
```

Comment: no, no ,element ordering is messed up.

Comment: @ZhengXiaodong - How is count `40%` ?

Comment: order asc, remove 40%

Comment: 40% by number of values? Or need count 40% from maximal, here 11 ?

Comment: I havae 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11, ten element, remove 40% is 1 2 3 4.

Comment: @ZhengXiaodong - Are missing values in same places like in sample data - in 8th column (full filled NaNs)?

Comment: I added some clarification to the description.

Comment: `df = df.mask(df.le(np.sum(~np.isnan(np.sort(df.to_numpy())), axis=1) * 0.4, axis=0), axis=0)
` so close, but not exactly what I wanted, if element is 1, 2, 31, 4, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5. 5 should be nan too.

Comment: thank you so much for wonderful answer, I've never known so many useful functions. `np.argsort(df)` is very important, it mark it clearly the position of the data column that I want to set nan.

Comment: @ZhengXiaodong - I do some test ansd hope it is final answer now.

Comment: on my god, that's a wonderful answer